# Pin Layout Unknown - 5-way navigational switch

Tags: switches

Completely at a loss, been searching for a datasheet or anything to help for a cou0ple hours... So I came to the only place where I can usually find help

Does anyone know what the pin layout of this 5-way navigational switch would be:

- Here's the Link to where I purchased it: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32815153642.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.113f4c4dmzJuNZ
- the only mark i see is letter D on the bottom right
- Unfortunately my wife took out my battery from my multimeter, without using a screwdriver so I have none right now

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have requested this question to be moved to electronics.stackexchange (since it's not related to Arduino).

Comment: Part number? What did it come from? Can you not buzz it out with a multimeter?

Comment: If it really is a set of (complex) on-off switches you should be able to figure it out with a buzzer/ohm/multi-meter or even a LED + resistor + battery.

Comment: A photo of the top would also be helpful in determining the actual part

Comment: Thank you all, I didn't know about "electronics.stackexchange" I'll move it there and add the suggestions above in so far as possible

Comment: added suggestions listed above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you everyone

I figured it out the hard way (hooked up an Arduino + led) and tried each trial and error style here's what i found

- Note the Bold "D" wit the arrow is the select button

[image]

Comment: that's not the `hard way` .... upvote for doing it yourself

Comment: the pinout even makes sense. not on this photo, but in normal position. left, right, forward, reverse

Comment: yup we are looking at the back, in this pic, so it really makes sense ;)

Answer (score 2):

It's called a 5-way switch in Chinese. Typical data (there are a number of makers):

[image]

Get your wife to replace that battery and check it out.

---

A more useful interpretation...

(note rotation of footprint below)  It agrees with yours if you roll your component to the right- otherwise, which edge is "up"?

Conventional component view (from the top, looking down):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is the part you are looking for:
https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/SKQUCAA010-ALPS.pdf

This PDF contains the pinout and internal schematics.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a 4-way joystick so it would be reasonable to expect that it has four switches. Since there are six points that means one of two things:

- Two of them are common (connected internally). These should be easy to identify with your meter on continuity mode. Then move the switch and figure out which pin is connected to common for each switch action.
- Some of these switches have a "push to select" contact as well. That would mean one common and five outputs. Yours doesn't look tall enough.

Our motto is, "No datasheet? No sale!".

Comment: Yea I pretty much decides with this order that "no datasheet" and cheap Chinese are to be avoided...

it is a 4-way with the added select button